# No autocomplete on PhpStorm for PHP constants

Tags: php, phpstorm, constants, code-completion

I have a little annoying problem on my PhpStorm IDE (Version 2017.3.4).

So I am trying to have suggestion of my constants defined on my project. But when I am trying to <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> there is none of my define constants.

All my constant are define like this in my project :

In a file :

```
$configFileDir = "configfile.php";

if (file_exists($configFileDir)) {
    require_once($configFileDir);

    try {
        define('CONSTANT1', $MY_CONSTANT["CONSTANT1"]);
        define('CONSTANT2', $MY_CONSTANT["CONSTANT2"]);
        ...
    }
}
```

All my constants are in an array called `$MY_CONSTANT` loaded in the file `configfile.php`.

Another thing : in my project these constants are define 2 times.

### What I have tried so far :

- File / Invalidate cache
- Changing PHP version in Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / PHP

If somebody have an idea this would be cool :) .

### Solution :

To get the suggestions from the IDE, I just removed the `try..catch` block arround the defines instructions. After that we can get the autocompletion for these constants :) . ( Big thanks to @LazyOne )

Comment: If you try `print_r($MY_CONSTANT["CONSTANT1"]);die;` inside `try` block. Do you get value of the constant ?

Comment: I am trying to get suggestion in my IDE my constants are well defined at runtime.

Comment: Actually I can not understand your question.

Comment: When you ctrl + space on phpStorm you get suggestion from the IDE. So here when I type CONST and after CTRL + space there is no suggestions of my constants :

CONSTANT1

neither 

CONSTANT2

Comment: Oh, ok got it. I think if you close PHP Storm and open it again will fix it. Actually when the IDE starts, it reads all projects loaded into it. And it also checks file relationships. Then it should start giving suggestions for the constants.

Comment: Already try it. But still no suggestions.

Comment: why do you call to constants in quotes?

Comment: Please create **standalone code sample** (few files) that would illustrate the problem and share it (so I can check it on my PC). Right now I cannot say what might be the issue here -- need more info.

Comment: Right now the reason looks to be that definition is done inside the `try..catch` block. Move it out of it and try that way. Also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38507

Comment: @LazyOne : Yes the cause is the `try..catch` block. When I remove it, it works.

So now, is it possible to have the suggestion with that `try..catch` block ?

Comment: No. Otherwise it would have worked already. Why do you need `try..catch` in first place?

Comment: It is a legacy code, I think the goal of that try catch is to print the constant wich is not define in the array.

Comment: Why would you want to define constants in a try..catch anyways? They don't throw exceptions, not even in case of error. Undefined index in array won't throw any exception also.

Comment: @DanFromGermany : The exception is throw if $MY_CONSTANT["CONSTANT1"] is not define in the previous file include : configfile.php. That is why it is done like that.

Comment: This does not throw an exception. It's a notice.

Comment: Ah yes, so I don't know why there is that try catch .

Comment: @Buisson Please make your solution as an answer and accept it -- it will help other users in the same situation (as it will be more visible/discoverable)

Comment: I have done that. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution :**

---

To get the suggestions from the IDE, I just removed the `try..catch` block arround the defines instructions.

After that we can get the autocompletion for these constants.

( Big thanks to **@LazyOne** )

Answer (score -1):

You can type hint PHPStorm:

```
<?php
/** @var CONSTANT1 constant */
define('CONSTANT1', 'test');
```

Comment: I tried that but still no suggestion, even if I restart / invalidate cache. see that screenshot : https://image.ibb.co/b2soa8/img_Suggestion.png